# Как сделать option по ширине как select?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

```css
#wgtmsr{
 width:150px;   
}

#wgtmsr option{
 width:100px;   
}
```

```html
<select name="wgtmsr" id="wgtmsr">
<option value="kg">Kg</option>
<option value="gm">Gm</option>
<option value="pound">Pound</option>
<option value="MetricTon">Metric adwd wad wad awd awd awd wad w adw ton</option>
<option value="litre">Litre</option>
<option value="ounce">Ounce</option>
</select>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы слово, которое больше по ширине делает опцию чем селект, переносилось на вторую строку(то-есть не выходило за рамки род. селекта)

Comment: например, не использовать option и select. Сделать свой отдельный визуализатор этого функционала.

Comment: Можно посмотреть реализацию тут: http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/qdWpya, если ок -выложу как ответ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Одним css - никак. Либо плагин использовать, либо самому скрипт написать.

Например я таким иногда пользуюсь:

```js
$('.select').each(function(){
  // Variables
  var $this = $(this),
   selectOption = $this.find('option'),
   selectOptionLength = selectOption.length,
   selectedOption = selectOption.filter(':selected'),
   dur = 500;

  $this.hide();
  // Wrap all in select box
  $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
  // Style box
  $('<div>',{
   class: 'select__gap',
   text: 'Please select' //Placeholder
  }).insertAfter($this);
  
  var selectGap = $this.next('.select__gap'),
   caret = selectGap.find('.caret');
  // Add ul list
  $('<ul>',{
   class: 'select__list'
  }).insertAfter(selectGap);  

  var selectList = selectGap.next('.select__list');
  // Add li - option items
  for(var i = 0; i < selectOptionLength; i++){
   $('<li>',{
    class: 'select__item',
    html: $('<span>',{
     text: selectOption.eq(i).text()
    })    
   })
   .attr('data-value', selectOption.eq(i).val())
   .appendTo(selectList);
  }
  // Find all items
  var selectItem = selectList.find('li');

  selectList.slideUp(0);
  selectGap.on('click', function(){
   if(!$(this).hasClass('on')){
    $(this).addClass('on');
    selectList.slideDown(dur);

    selectItem.on('click', function(){
     var chooseItem = $(this).data('value');

     $('select').val(chooseItem).attr('selected', 'selected');
     selectGap.text($(this).find('span').text());

     selectList.slideUp(dur);
     selectGap.removeClass('on');
    });
    
   } else {
    $(this).removeClass('on');
    selectList.slideUp(dur);
   }
  });  

 });
```

```css
/* #wgtmsr{
 width:150px;  
}

#wgtmsr option{
 width:100px;   
} */


/* Стилизация селекта для примера: */
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Выпадающий список: */
.select ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #0095ff;
  width:100px;
}

/* Пункт списка: */
.select ul li {
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Наведение на пункт списка: */
.select ul li:hover {
  background: #0095ff;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Выбор option "Please Select": */
.select__gap {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  width:150px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

/* Стрелочка: */
.select__gap:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  
<select name="wgtmsr" id="wgtmsr" class="select">
  <option value="kg">Kg</option>
  <option value="gm">Gm</option>
  <option value="pound">Pound</option>
  <option value="MetricTon">Metric adwd wad wad awd awd awd wad w adw ton</option>
  <option value="litre">Litre</option>
  <option value="ounce">Ounce</option>
</select>
```